# Неадекватный Segmentation fault

Tags: qt, c++

Следующей строчкой кода устанавливаю обработчик события:

```
QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget,
SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex))
(QModelIndex)), this,
SLOT(tree_widget_item_selected(QModelIndex)));
```

В слоте `tree_widget_item_selected` пытаюсь сделать следующую вещь:

```
selected = selected.parent();
```

При дебаге данной строки получаю **Segmentation fault**. При чём если не дебажить, а просто использовать программу по назначению всё работает как и ожидалось.
Win7, Qt 5.1.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а добавьте проверку, что selected не NULL.

    if (selected) {
      selected = selected.parent();
    else {
      qDebug() << "selected = NULL";
      return;
    }

Comment: @KoVadim пишет о невозможности приведения QModelIndex к булеановскому типу, там в принципе метод есть, isValid называется, его проходит нормально. Метод вернет false если объект QModelIndex пустой.

Comment: поспешил немножко. я решил, что selected - это указатель.

Можете привести минимальный пример, что бы баг повторился?

Comment: а какой там пример может быть... selected = selected.parent();
Это строчка находится в цикле пока selected.isValid(), но суть в том, что даже при первом проходе вылетает ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

У вас рушится stack memory, это системная ошибка и вы можете попытаться исправить ее, изменив распределние памяти в ней.У вас ведь при дебаге в код добавляется debug-информация!

Comment: И как это сделать?

Comment: @voipp Вы хоть бы в википедии посмотрели, [что такое segmentation fault,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) прежде чем использовать такие замечательные фразы как "разрушение stack memory".